# jQuery animate div up down on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this HTML

```
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two   <br/> <br/>
   Two
</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four   <br/> <br/>
   Four   <br/> <br/>
   Four
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#two").hide();
    $("#four").hide();
    $("#one").click(function () {

        $("#four").slideUp("slow", function () {

        });
        $("#three").slideToggle("slow,", function () {

        });

        $("#two").slideToggle("slow", function () {

        });
    });

    $("#three").click(function () {
        $("#four").slideToggle("slow,", function () {});
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is show div one and three one under another.

When I click div one, I want div two to show (animate), and div three (and div four, if div three is clicked too) to move position under div two (with same animation).

When I click div one again, I want div two to hide (animate) and div three (and div four, if div three clicked) to go back to the position they had before.

**Here's JSFiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/6ynnR/

Comment: It would help if you included jQuery in the fiddle - that's your problem ;) http://jsfiddle.net/6ynnR/

Comment: Thank you for that. Still, my problem is that div three and div four hide when i click on div one. I want them both to move under div two after div one is clicked and then move back up when div one is clicked again

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want something like this: [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5nHzC/)

Updated jQuery:

```
$("#two, #four").hide();

$("#one").click(function () {
    $("#two").slideToggle(function () {
        $("#four").slideUp();
    });
});

$("#three").click(function () {
    $("#four").slideToggle(function () {
        $("#two").slideUp()
    });
});
```

Alternatively, here is another approach: [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vwpS/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following code and you're good to go :D

```
    $("#four").slideUp("slow", function () {

    });
    $("#three").slideToggle("slow,", function () {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you,

I added conditional statement:

```
if(($("#two").is(":visible"))&&($("#four").is(":visible"))){

      $("#four").slideToggle("slow,", function () {});
      $("#two").slideToggle("slow,", function () {});

    }
```

and removed two functions :

```
$("#four").slideUp("slow", function () {
    });

$("#three").slideToggle("slow,", function () {
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uY73z/19/